# influx result set to datetime column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, series

i have influxdb result set as

```
results2 = ResultSet({'('options_price_reference_limits', None)': [{'time': '2022-03-22T16:37:39.643127Z', 'lower_boundary': -439.8286562572736, 'mark_price': 144.060885, 'symbol': 'C-BTC-44000-250322', 'upper_boundary': 556.8514272321878}, {'time': '2022-03-22T16:37:44.671990Z', 'lower_boundary': -445.06319445515476, 'mark_price': 144.615283, 'symbol': 'C-BTC-44000-250322', 'upper_boundary': 563.4589659718127}, {'time': '2022-03-22T16:37:49.715605Z', 'lower_boundary': -441.5881618331249, 'mark_price': 144.688937, 'symbol': 'C-BTC-44000-250322', 'upper_boundary': 559.0723733380117}, {'time': '2022-03-22T16:37:54.792814Z', 'lower_boundary': -455.1554628099913, 'mark_price': 146.319068, 'symbol': 'C-BTC-44000-250322', 'upper_boundary': 576.1976471885248})
```

Im converting it into dataframe by

```
df = pd.DataFrame(results2)
```

but the time format is coming as `2022-03-22T16:37:39.643127Z`

i want it to be as `2022-03-22 16:37:39`

Tried with

```
df['time2']=pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
```

but its not as i mentioned. its showing as "2022-03-22 16:37:39.643127+00:00
"
Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for remove miliseconds with [`Series.dt.tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_convert.html) for remove timezones:

```
A = ['2022-03-22T16:37:39.643127Z','2022-03-22T16:37:39.643127Z']
df = pd.DataFrame(A,columns = ['time'])

print (pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.floor('S').dt.tz_convert(None))
0   2022-03-22 16:37:39
1   2022-03-22 16:37:39
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Only removed timezones:

```
print (pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.tz_convert(None))
0   2022-03-22 16:37:39.643127
1   2022-03-22 16:37:39.643127
Name: time, dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pd.to_datetime(df['time']).dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Output:

```
0    2022-03-22 16:37:39
1    2022-03-22 16:37:44
2    2022-03-22 16:37:49
3    2022-03-22 16:37:54
Name: time, dtype: object
```

Comment: 2022-03-22 16:37:39.643127+00:00 for floor option and T is there for str extract option.How to remove those as well.

Comment: ok, its working but its type time or string, If string please add something to make it as timestamp..

Comment: You can use to_datetime again on the result.